# What is the probability that I live in 2 different houses with the same door number at different points in my life?

Tags: probability, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

The first house I used to live in at the door number 486. After a few years time, I lived in another house with the same door number 486 which I thought was incredibly lucky.

I was curious what is the probability that this can happen. Can someone explain what is the probability and how to calculate it? One of the challenges I was not able to wrap around is that, even if we assume door numbers start at 1, we don’t know at what number it stops for any given street.

Some additional information if it’s useful:

- I have lived in 13 different addresses in my entire life
- Both my 1st house and my 5th house has the same door number 486

I am not a mathematician, so forgive me for not trying to answer this myself. I hope you find this as interesting as I do.

Comment: I do not think that a mathematical model of such complex daily life situations will be accurate enough for a satisfactoring answer. Too many unknown factors influence the final probability. We can find the probability only under several assumptions we will have to make, whether this gives finally a reliable probability ? I have doubts.

Comment: That said, I would consider it to be quite surprising/astonishing/remarkable. But it is hard to calculate how surprising/astonishing/remarkable it is. We at least have to know more about how door numbers are distributed. I do not know them (only house numbers in a street or door numbers in a hotel , but not private door numbers). Maybe more details help.

Comment: [This histogram](https://38.media.tumblr.com/d0d81ab8368d8c2b54f62e79ae23af4c/tumblr_inline_neyk43DK6s1szvr4h.png) was lifted from a comment in a youtube video and shows the distribution of street address numbers in Manhattan.  One could, presumably, make similar histograms for other parts of a country and attempt to extrapolate.  That said, numbering systems surely depend on the local area.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_numbering

Comment: That all being said, coincidences happen all the time.  If it were not the case that your attention was drawn to the fact that you've lived in two similarly numbered houses, then perhaps you will have noticed something else mundane and seemingly unlikely such as every time this week when you enter your local shop the same song was playing on the speakers, or you met two Johns exactly one week apart etc...

Comment: @JMoravitz That histogram captures part of what was my thought. Most door numbers are going to be 2 or 3 digits. Door numbers as you go up are going to be less frequent. For instance, a door number in the 800s or 900s are very rare compared to a door number in the 100s or 200s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a rough guess, let's assume that there are $100,000$ possible house numbers that are all equally likely. If a person lives in $10$ different houses, the chance that they'll have a repeat house number is
$$
1 - \biggl( 1 - \frac1{100000} \biggr)\biggl( 1 - \frac2{100000} \biggr)\cdots \biggl( 1 - \frac9{100000} \biggr) \approx 0.00045
$$
(in other words, a $0.045$% chance, or about $1$ in $2{,}222$). The fact that house numbers are not equally likely means that the chances are actually higher than this.

We must also remember that:

- this is not the only coincidence that could have happened, so the odds of *some* interesting coincidence are much higher;
- there are billions of people in the world, so even $1$ in $2{,}222$ events happen millions of times.

Comment: That is a good way to put an upper bound. 1 in 2000 doesn’t seem to be a very rare event. And If you think about it, how often do you even see door numbers in the 1000s or 10000s. So the actual probability is going to be even higher.